# Query_while in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How would I do such a similar query with laravel?

```
$GLOBALS['db']->query_while("SELECT * FROM games 
WHERE id_gioco='".$id_gioco."' AND id_utente='".$USER['id']."'");
```

In the documentation of laravel and Eloquent, I found nothing on query_while.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what a while query is , but the following should work. If you chain 2 where clauses it will make it an AND where()

```
$games = Game::where('id_gioco', $id_gioco)->where('id_utente', $user->id)->get()
```